# What does logman query providers -pid really do?

Tags: windows, events, msdn, etw, logman

Apparently, `logman query providers -pid $pid` allows us to see which providers the process `$pid` writes to.

But how does the process `$pid` open a handle to the providers? What's the API?

Comment: did you find an answer?

Comment: @AloisKraus No.